# Frobenius norm minimization subject to diagonal constraints

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, non-convex-optimization

Edit: I have now reformulated the problem in a more readable way.

I have a not so complicated minimization program I need a bit help with.

I am given three positive semidefinite matrices: $R, \Gamma, S \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$.

I am trying to minimize the following original objective function for $\boldsymbol{d}, \boldsymbol{a}$ and $\beta$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{a},\beta}{\text{minimize }}
&& \|\text{diag}(\boldsymbol{d})^{\frac{1}{2}}~R~\text{diag}(\boldsymbol{d})^{\frac{1}{2}} + \text{diag}(\boldsymbol{a})^{\frac{1}{2}}~\Gamma~\text{diag}(\boldsymbol{a})^{\frac{1}{2}} - \beta S\|_F^2 \\
& \text{s. t. }  && \boldsymbol{d}>\mathbb{0}, \boldsymbol{a}>\mathbb{0}, \beta>0
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $\boldsymbol{d}, \boldsymbol{a} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

This problem is definitely non-convex. My first motivation is to get solutions in an alternative manner. How do I impose the constraints. Now I am not so sure how to approach.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you get the last three terms in the trace? It looks wrong.

Comment: You are right to suspect, but as $D$ and $A$ are diagonal, putting them together do not change the outcome. However, I shouldn't have done that, as I am solving a minimization criteria, I'd better put the diagonal constraint. But I don't know any better way to do that.

Comment: But $Tr(D^{1/2}RD^{1/2}A^{1/2}\Gamma A^{1/2})$ is definitely not equal to $Tr(DR\Gamma A)$. BTW, you can leave away all the $\cdot^H$'s because they are all hermitian anyways.

Comment: Umm, I numerically checked in MATLAB, and I am getting same trace values for both cases. If you take $X^\frac{1}{2}X^\frac{1}{2}=X$, and all $D, A$s are diagonal, you will get the same values I suppose.

Comment: No, you don't because, for example, $D$ and $R$ don't commute. Even for $A  = I$ this is false. Here is an example:$$D = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&4\end{pmatrix},\quad R = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix},\quad\text{and}\quad\Gamma = \begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: You are right, the particular test case I was considering was giving me such scenario. I was wrong. Let me correct those terms. Thank you for pointing out. Regardless, do you think, the methodology I stated in the question is pointing to a right direction?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: The minimum is attained at $D=A=0$, $\beta=0$. I think you may need to reformulate your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much pointing that out. I have reformulated the problem now.

Comment: That's not enough at all. Now the optimal value is zero but may not be attained; it's like asking to minimize $|x|$ subject to the constraint $x>0$. You need to go back to whatever original problem motivated this minimization and reformulate it from there. Maybe you should start by adding your motivation to the question.